# Oracle 11g ORA-12560 and ORA 01031

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

I have installed Oracle 11g R2 Express and I am trying to connect to it but got errors:

```
sqlplus '/ as sysdba'

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Cz Lip 2 15:20:39 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

And also when I try like this:

```
sqlplus 'sys as sysdba'

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Cz Lip 2 15:20:39 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-02560:  TNS:protocol adapter error
```

ORACLE_HOME:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
```

ORACLE_SID:

```
XE
```

OracleServiceXE, OracleXEClrAgent, OracleXETNSListener are running in services.msc

When I try to start OracleMTSRecoveryService I got:

```
Error no 1: Incorrect function
```

So It's not working

Listener:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = me.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

SQLNET:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)
```

TNSNAMES:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = me.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

OS: Windows 8.1
I do not have admin privilages on that PC.
I have no idea why it is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Change PORT number and try again.